# Print variable names in csv using psych::describe()

Tags: r

I'm using R's psych package.  When I use `describe()` as below to get descriptive statistics of variables, their names appeared in the console but do not appear in the exported csv file.
How can I get this column printed, so that I know which results belong to which variable.

```
library(psych)
descriptive2 <- describe(mtcars)
write.csv(descriptive2, "temp.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any issue with your code other than the misspelling of `write.csv`. The variables are in the row names which are by default printed in the csv file.

```
library(psych)
write.csv(data.frame(describe(mtcars)),"temp.csv")
```

Alternative will be:

```
descriptive2 <- data.frame(describe(mtcars))
descriptive2$vars <- row.names(descriptive2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the argument `row.names = TRUE` when exporting your csv file. As mentioned @Adam Quek, make sure to correct the function `write.csv()`.

```
library(psych)
descriptive2<-describe(mtcars)
write.csv(descriptive2,"temp.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```